# Rails: Render actions with a specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, render

In my Rails3 application I add a specific match for `edit` my `Post` model as:

```
match '/edit' => 'posts#edit', :as => 'post_edit'
```

So, I overwrite the default path of the `edit` action. - Now if any errors occurs in the `update` action, it will render the `edit` action with settting the URL path with the default `edit` path `/posts/1`.

How can I overwrite that to render the `edit` action with setting the URL path as `/edit` instead of `posts/1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually seeing the URL for "update", the default path for edit would be `/posts/1/edit`.  I don't think you will be able to change what the URL displays using `render :action`.  An alternate, although somewhat sloppy, method would be to redirect and save the @post object in the session or flash.  If you do not save the @post object, you will lose the error messages from the update.

```
if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
  #business as usual
else
  session[:post] = @post
  redirect_to post_edit(@post)
end
```

Note that it is bad practice to save the whole object in the session (especially large objects), so you may instead want to only send the error message string with the flash and render that in the view.  These are both rather hackish methods, but I don't really see an elegant way to do this.

Out of curiosity, why do you want to change the default URL? Is it necessary?

Comment: actually, you are correct ;-) Thanks for catching that! answer updated